# PHP MySQL SELECT newest entry grouped by an ID and ordered by timestamp

Tags: mysql

I am working on an problem regarding Selecting data from two MySQL tables.

```
First table holds messages | messages | (id, msg_group_id, to_user_id, from_user_id, datetime)

Second table holds user data | profiles | (user_id, name, firstname, ...)
```

ATM it works the way, that I can select *ALL* messages with a certain 'to_id' and by adding a JOIN statement getting the name and firstname of the user who sends the message.

My problem now is that I can not figure out a way to *ONLY* select the newest message of a certain msg_group_id.

I already tried GROUP BY msg_group_id combined with ORDER BY datetime DESC.

But that only throws the very first entry in message table. But I want to last one. :-)

I hope you can help me. :-)

My actual SQL statement:

```
SELECT LEFT(messages.message, 10) AS message, 
`messages`.`msg_group_id`,  
`messages`.`datetime`,  
`profiles`.`name`,  
`profiles`.`firstname`  
FROM `messages`  
LEFT JOIN `profiles`  
ON `messages`.`from_user_id` = `profiles`.`user_id`  
WHERE `to_user_id` = '2'  
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC  
LIMIT 20;
```

Thanks in Advance

Sample INPUT:

[messages]

```
|id|msg_group_id|to_user_is|from_user_id|message       |datetime|
0  | 1          | 1        | 2          | Hello World1 | 2015-12-21 10:42:00
1  | 1          | 1        | 2          | Hello World2 | 2015-12-21 10:43:00
2  | 1          | 1        | 2          | Hello World3 | 2015-12-21 10:44:00
```

[profiles]

```
user_id|name    |firstname|
1      | Test   | User
2      | Thanks | Worldname
```

Result (what I don't want)

```
message|msg_group_id|datetime|name|firstname
Hello World1 | 1 | 2015-12-21 10:42:00 | Thanks | Worldname
```

Result (what I want)

```
message|msg_group_id|datetime|name|firstname
Hello World3 | 1 | 2015-12-21 10:44:00 | Thanks | Worldname
```

Comment: Thanks guys for correcting my formating mistakes ;-)

Comment: can you add sample input and output?

Comment: just added some...but i can not find a way to format it in an appropriate way do I have to mark it as code? --- ha at least the formatting works (in a way) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

May be this query can help:

```
SELECT m.message, m.msg_group_id, m.datetime, u.name, u.firstname 
FROM message as m, profiles as u
WHERE m.from_user_id = u.user_id 
GROUP BY m.msg_group_id
ORDER BY m.datetime DESC
```

Or use [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

```
SELECT m.message, m.msg_group_id, m.datetime, u.name, u.firstname 
FROM message as m
INNER JOIN profiles as u ON m.from_user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY m.msg_group_id
ORDER BY m.datetime DESC
```

Comment: if you want newest record then just use `ORDER BY m.datetime DESC`

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you very much. But it doesn't do what I expect.
Expecting one user receives more than 1 message this will not work. I guess.

Comment: it should give output as you have mentioned

Comment: @nira can you please check once my updated answer? try my first query

Comment: yes I tried it again. It only delivers 1 result as the LIMIT 1 says. But the user already has more than 1 message with different msg_group_id's

Comment: I also did that :-) But then it shows all messages :-)

Comment: yes it'll show all message bcoz that user_id condition meets the criteria

Comment: What I want is:
- Get for every msg_group_id only the very newest msg
- Get to this message the name&firstname of the sender (from_user)

Comment: @nira i added group by condition.. see whether it can help

Comment: yes I already tried this as well...that delivers the same as my (crazy left join statement in the question) it shows the very oldest message in the table. I am confused about it as we set it DESC.

Comment: it should descending the order by date

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved the Problem with the help of another thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313140/4493030

My SQL Statement as follows:

```
SELECT `messages`.*, `profiles`.`nick_name` 
FROM `messages`  
LEFT JOIN `profiles`  
ON `messages`.`from_user_id` = `profiles`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT konversation_id, MAX(id) AS maxid FROM messages
WHERE messages.to_user_id = 2 
GROUP BY konversation_id) AS b
ON messages.id = b.maxid
WHERE `to_user_id` = '2'  
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC  
LIMIT 20;
```

Thanks to all of you who tried to help.

I found a way to tight it down

```
SELECT messages.to_user_id, messages.msg_group_id, MAX(messages.id) AS maxid, messages.from_user_id, profiles.name 
FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN profiles 
ON messages.from_user_id = profiles.user_id 
WHERE messages.to_user_id = 2 
GROUP BY msg_group_id
```